# How to repeat a section based on a nested array

Tags: mustache

I'm using mustache.js and would like my template to display the text six times, once for each value in data.result.options[0]

**JS**

```
data = {result : {"id": "AAA", "options" : [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 2, 3]}}
```

**Template**

```
{{#result.options[0]}}
<span>Show me six times.</span>
{{/result.options[0]}}
```

When I try this though, nothing is rendered. Is it possible to do it without changing the data structure?

jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/TbuP5/1/

Answer (score 0):

I was playing around and this worked:

**Template**

```
{{#result.options.0}}
<span>Show me six times.</span>
{{/result.options.0}}
```